# Fading out a JButton until the JCheckbox is selected

Tags: java

I am making a small program in java and want to be able to fade out the "continue" button untill the the checkbox is selected. Does anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: use `setVisible` method

Comment: Or `setEnabled()`, depending on what you mean by "fade out".

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton


public class CheckBox extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    private JButton btnButton;
    private JCheckBox chkCheckbox;              

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new CheckBox());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public CheckBox() {
        btnButton = new JButton();
        chkCheckbox = new JCheckBox();

        btnButton.setText("Continue");

        chkCheckbox.setText("Agree?");
        chkCheckbox.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
                btnButton.setVisible(((JCheckBox)evt.getSource()).isSelected());
            }
        });


        add(chkCheckbox);
        add(btnButton);
    }                                        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setEnabled(false);
```

Then you would add an ItemListener to the checkbox to enable the button when the check box is selected.

See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Check Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more information.